# How to replace texts in conf file

Tags: bash, sed, delimiter, string-substitution

I need to replace the followin parameters in a conf file:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

I need to set `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/www.something.ee`

www.something.ee is a variable `$WEBPAGE`

So far I have this:

`sed -i "s/DocumentRoot /var/www/html /DocumentRoot /var/www/$WEBPAGE/g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/$WEBPAGE.conf`

However since it contains slashes the command does not want to run. Putting apostrophes around them does not seem to want to work:

> couldn't open file ww/html' /'DocumentRoot /var/www/www.something.ee'/g: No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with sed you can user any delimiter...

```
 sed 's@oldText@newText@g'
 sed 's#oldText#newText#g'
```

so if the `/` is bothering you, use a different delimiter.

Comment: Ok, it does not give an error anymore, however I can not get it to save into the conf file, in the conf file still is old information.

Comment: Got it to work, the problem was in an additional spacebar that was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use a delimiter other than slash. You also do not need the g option as there are no multiple occurrences of the search

```
sed -i "s!DocumentRoot /var/www/html !DocumentRoot /var/www/$WEBPAGE!" /etc/apache2/sites-available/$WEBPAGE.conf
```